# error with readOGR cannot open data source, cannot open layer

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to read a shapefile named shapefile.shp using readOGR. I am using the following code:

```
shp=readOGR('C:/Users/koley/OneDrive/Desktop/My Folder 2-MK-thinkpad/Data/CL/shapefile.shp')
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

I further tried using

```
shp=readOGR(dsn="C:\\Users\\koley\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\My Folder 2-MK-thinkpad\\Data\\CL", layer="shapefile")
```

And it gives me this error:

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  :
> Cannot open layer

Can someone please help me read this shapefile? I am new to working with shapefiles and unable to understand what is going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `file.exsts()` return TRUE for those paths? I don't think the second one looks correct because ``\`` is an escape sequence for R strings. It should be ``\\`` or `/`

Comment: I think I have \\ in the second one, so that should be correct, right?